# How can I detect copying files from dokan drive to the same dokan drive?

Tags: c#, fuse, dokan

I need to catch the event to copy file within dokan drive. I am using C# dokan mirror-drive project. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Copying works in such a way that original file is first opened via CreateFile callback, a copy of that file is created via CreateFile callback, original file is read via ReadFile callback, and the copy is written via WriteFile callback. As far as my (fairly limited) knowledge goes, there is no explicit way to detect copying.

You could detect copying a file in the same directory by the "Copy" suffix.

I could be wrong, I don't know that much about Dokan. I only wrote an in-memory file system for a collage Operating Systems course assignment.